# php printf using %s for digits

Tags: php, integer, printf

I was wondering why not to use `printf %s` for all kind of variables since it works. I've been using it for so many years. In the manual it says you should use `%d` for integers and decimals, but why? What is the difference of using `%s` for integers and decimals against using `%d` for them? I don't use to give the integer values directly to the `printf` function but they mostly come from database with type integer and `printf` works fine. Is it just to be able to give the integers directly to `printf` function without quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to perform some mathematical operation within printf function, then you would require "%d".

For example,

```
printf("%d", $x/2); (correct)

printf("%s", $x/2); (incorrect)
```

Because you won't be able to perform mathematical operations then. Hope it helps!